# Java Error In WebSocket Server

Tags: android, sockets, cordova, websocket, serversocket

I was working with the Project at https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket.
The server Worked well. Now i wanted to host the server on an Android Device (a PhoneGap Project). But I am getting this error.

Where is the Problem? This is the error I get in console. any way to get rid of this problem?

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=4996, tid=6072   fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

 JRE version: 7.0_25-b16  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )  Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:  C:\Users\Sourav\workspace\Phone Gap\hs_err_pid4996.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can RFC 6455 protocol in webSocket for android browser